# How to maintain jquery after ajax change the html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Basically I got some jquery like this:

```
$(".dates").on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
    $(".dates").on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
```

and below this code I got an ajax request that change the content of its parent element:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "includes/calendar.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            "count" : count
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#calendar').html(data);
    }
```

the class .dates are elements in the span with id `#calendar` and the data that ajax received is another set of dates with class `.dates`

but after the ajax request completes and changes the html in `#calendar`, the jquery on dates no long works.

is there any way to maintain the jquery on the `.dates` elements after ajax request without copying the jquery code inside of ajax success?

Comment: You need to do event delegation. Google for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use event delegation since you are dealing with dynamic elements

```
$('#calendar').on("mouseover", ".dates", function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}).on("mouseout", ".dates", function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delegation as you are using dynamic elements

Change your code as

```
$("#calendar").on("mouseover",".dates", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
$("#calendar").on("mouseout", ".dates",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

For more details and possibilities, read about the `.on(events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject))` method in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".dates", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
$(document).on("mouseout",".dates",  function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use on

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".dates", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
$(document).on("mouseout",".dates",  function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```